# Filter in grid with custom renderer product_id

Tags: magento-1.7, grid, filter

My problem is: Filter for columns with custom renderer not working. I tried that,

```
protected function _prepareColumns() {

    ...

    $this->addColumn('tipo_producto', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Tipo Producto'),
        'index'     =>'tipo_producto',  
        'renderer'  => 'organizadosreports/widget_grid_column_renderer_tipoproducto',           
        'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_myCustomFilter'),
    ));

    ...

}
```

Renderer is:

```
class Organizados_Reports_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Tipoproducto
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    protected $_defaultWidth = 100;

    /**
     * Returns value of the row
     *
     * @param Varien_Object $row
     * @return mixed|string
     */
    protected function _getValue(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        try {
            $product_id = $row->getData('product_id');
            $attributeValue = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id)->getAttributeText('tipo_producto');          
            return $attributeValue;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return '';
        }   
    }
}
```

My custom filter

```
protected function _myCustomFilter($collection, $column, Varien_Object $row)
{
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return $this;
    }

    $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where("main_table.tipo_producto like ?","$value");

    return $this;
}
```

Error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:99:"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'main_table.tipo_producto' in 'where clause'";i:1;s:6514:"#0 ...
```

Could anybody help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Does your table have a column named 'tipo_producto' ?

Comment: What does your getCollection look like for the grid?

Comment: Hi, I have thisclass Mymodule_Reports_Model_Mysql4_Proforma extends Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Item_Collection
{

    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();

        $this->join(
            array('order'=>'sales/order'),
            "main_table.order_id = order.entity_id",
            $cols = array(
                'increment_id'=>'increment_id',
                'customer_fullname' => new Zend_Db_Expr("CONCAT(customer_firstname, ' ', customer_lastname)"),
            ));
    
        return $this;

Comment: I don't know how join tipo_producto attribute to my collection. I think that this is my problem.